# print in python without using 'print' command

Tags: python, syntax

I created a simple python script which has the following two lines:

```
a =2
a
```

When I run this script in Ubuntu terminal (by typing "python3.4 script.py"), nothing is displayed. But when I type the above two commands (or lines) in a python interpreter, the second command ('a') displays the value of the variable 'a', i.e. 2.

**My question**: Why does the second command ('a') behave differently when run as a part of a script as compared to when run as an individual command in the python interpreter?

Comment: Because you aren't in a REPL when you run a script?

Comment: Second answer in that post

Comment: @Bingo No. REPL - [Read-Eval-Print Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

Answer (score 2):

You are giving a value of `2` to the variable `a`.

When you type `a` in the Python interpreter it will output the representation of your input as `repr()` would.

That's why entering `a` returns `2`.

Comment: Even without the variable, entering `2` into the interactive interpreter will `repr` it and spit out `2`. The question was why running the script doesn't have output